# how hidden TextInput IOS Keyboard top area (ok button)

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VEfz.jpg)

i want to hidden this area
What shall I do?
thanks

Comment: Please share your TextInput Code

Comment: Check returnKeyType prop in TextInput

Comment: tranks @BhavyaKoshiya

Answer (score 0):

```
        <TextInput
          returnKeyType={'default'}
          autoFocus
          style={{ paddingBottom: 97,height: 238,padding: 0}}
          // blurOnSubmit={true}
          multiline={true}
          // onSubmitEditing={onConfirm}
          // maxLength={30}
          // autoCorrect={false}
          clearButtonMode={'always'}
          textContentType={'none'}
          placeholder={'Please enter note'}
          placeholderTextColor={'#454545'}
          value={note}
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically
          caretHidden
          keyboardType="default"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          contextMenuHidden={false}
          inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID}
          // disableFullscreenUI={false}
          onChangeText={noteChanged}
        ></TextInput>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove these props from `TextInput`

1. `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically`
2. `returnKeyType={'default'}`